# the latency of h.264 is more than 800ms,however the latency of vp9 nearly 500ms

Tags: webrtc

i recently added x264 to encode  and ffmepg to decode on webrtc, i tested the latency of h.264 is more than 800ms,however the latency of vp9 nearly 500ms. 
at the begining of sending and recieving video, it has nearly 300ms latency. but after a few seconds, the latency is up to 800ms~900ms.  i have no idea what's caused it.  thanks in advance!
the setting of x264 is below:
    (width x height : 320 x 240)

```
x264_param_default_preset(&encoder_params, "veryfast", "zerolatency")
x264_param_apply_profile(&encoder_params, "baseline")
encoder_params.rc.i_lookahead = 0;
encoder_params.i_sync_lookahead = 0;
encoder_params.i_bframe = 0;
encoder_params.b_sliced_threads = 1;
encoder_params.b_vfr_input = 0;
encoder_params.rc.b_mb_tree = 0;
encoder_params.i_fps_num = 8;
encoder_params.i_fps_den = 1;
encoder_params.i_keyint_max = 8 * 5;
encoder_params.rc.f_rf_constant = 30;
encoder_params.rc.f_rf_constant_max = 45;
encoder_params.i_level_idc = 11;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely be getting better latency than that, I get <200ms on a raspberry pi with gstreamer.

2 possible things I'd look at:

1. is the encoder running out of CPU ? If it is can you allocate more threads/CPUs?
2. is there a buffer somewhere ? (I found gstreamer likes to buffer a second or so of data stuff unless you tell it not to).

Comment: cpu usage less than 5%.  i use 4 threads. the buffer is allocated when use.

Answer (score 0):

- What happens if you do `veryfast` -> `ultrafast`
- Can you try lowering your keyframe interval? I would try doing 8 for now.

I use a similar configuration for an application [here](https://github.com/pion/example-webrtc-applications/blob/master/internal/gstreamer-src/gst.go#L56) and have been pretty happy with the latency. I haven't measured myself, but it seems better then 1 Second!